# Extracting substring before ".." using R

Tags: gsub

I would like to extract "PAN3.AS1" from "PAN3.AS1..100288730."
How could I do this? I know gsub() function can do this but I didn't know what to write.

Comment: Use `strsplit` and escape the dots with double back-slashes, like this: `strsplit("PAN3.AS1..100288730.", "\\.\\.")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a replacement approach:

```
x <- "PAN3.AS1..100288730"
sub("\\.\\..*$", "", x)

[1] "PAN3.AS1"
```

The reason I chose to do it by removing ellipsis followed by all content to the right is that should the input not have an ellipsis, the above approach would just return the input, which is the behavior we want.

Answer (score 0):

i dont familiar with `gsub()` but you can use simple regex - `"PAN3.AS1..100288\n\n\n730.".replace(/\.\.[\s\S]+/, '')`